# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /webtech/login.jsp at line 6

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, tomcat

Its basicaly a simple project to check login and password...

i did all the things possible to figure out the error...but i cannot somehow get over it...can anyone please help and provide solution for me.

i have a html file name **Login.html** and a jsp file named **login.jsp**

mysql port no. is **3306** with username and password **sait**

my tomcat port no. is **8801**.

**Login.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="login.jsp" method="post">
User name :<input type="text" name="usr" />
password :<input type="password" name="pwd" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
String userid=request.getParameter("usr"); 
String pswd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sait","root","root"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login where username='"+userid+"'"); 
if(rs.next()) 
{ 
if(rs.getString("password").equals(pswd)) 
{ 
out.println("welcome"+userid); 

} 
else 
{ 
out.println("Invalid password try again"); 
} 
} 
%>
```

i created a folder in **C:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\webtech**
and placed this 2 files **\webetech\Login.html** and **\webtech\login.jsp**

i opened mysql and created a database named "sait"..then changed the database to "sait" using the command "use sait;" in mysql.

then i executed the following code

```
mysql>create table login(username varchar(10),password varchar(10));
>insert into login values("sait","sait");
>select * from login;
```

all executed successfully..

then i placed **mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin** in d destination **C:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 7.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar**

now if i go to

```
 http://localhost:8081/webtech/Login.html
```

i get the **login page**..but after i submit i get **HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /webtech/login.jsp at line 6**

Plssss help

Comment: could paste the stacktrace

Comment: Do you have mysql jar in your application??? and paste the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might get `NullpointerException` . so just print the values of

```
String userid=request.getParameter("usr"); 
String pswd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
out.print(userid + "" + pswd);
```

and check it out . **Also its highly discourged to use the java codes in jsp pages . try using a servlet to establish JDBC**

You should also add `try/catch` block your code to catch any exception if thrown ,

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
String userid=request.getParameter("usr"); 
String pswd=request.getParameter("pwd");
out.print(userid + "" + pswd); 
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sait","root","root"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from login where username='"+userid+"'"); 
while(rs.next()) 
{ 
if(rs.getString("password").equals(pswd)) 
{ 
out.println("welcome"+userid);
} 
else 
{ 
out.println("Invalid password try again"); 
} 
}}
catch(Exception e) 
{
out.print("Exception is " + e);
}
%>
```

If this didnt solve your issue . please post us the exception you are getting

Hope this helps !!

Comment: you should must add the new line in this particular line: `out.print(userid + "" + pswd);`